# Code correction - Hide a profile from visitors with a specific role

Tags: buddypress, profiles, private

The following code i tried to hide the profile of subscriber's role of user not logged in but I need it to be visible to the administrator and  shop_manager, how can I do it?

```
add_action('bp_ready', 'hide_profile_subscriber');

function hide_profile_subscriber() {

$user = get_userdata( bp_displayed_user_id() );
if ( ! in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    return;
} 

wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') . '/restringido' );

}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: This code will only redirect if the user is a subscriber. So there's no reason administrators or shop managers shouldn't be able to access the page.

Comment: Hi Jacob I am testing on my site, if you are a visitor you redirect it and if you are an administrator too. im using bp_displayed_user_id

Comment: Use `get_current_user_id()` if you want to restrict based on the current user, rather than the owner of the profile.

Comment: I thought about it but the only user profile (subscriber) that is private, the rest is public. I can't find the way